# Exist a gramatical qualifiers guide to resolve a qualifiers excercise?

Tags: grammar, qualifiers

I want to fill the exercise but I just do it with **trial and error** until I get all correct, exist something I'm missing like a grammatical guide to answer this exercise?
[image]

Comment: I take it that when yiu say "exist" you mean "does there exist" or better simply "is there".

Comment: choosing an appropriate qualifier here depends on the context and meaning as well as the grammar, nor is there usually a single correct answer.. For example where "pretty" is correct "rather" can also be used.

Comment: You have to learn what words modify nouns (these are called adjectives) and what words modify verbs or other modifiers (these are called adverbs).  A dictionary can help.  Most modifier words can only do one or the other.